# How to set proxy in HttpComponentsMessageSender?

Tags: proxy, spring-integration, gateways

I am working behind a firewall,where i am trying to access a soap web service.
i went over through the internet,but couldn't find anything for setting proxy in .
I am calling the webservice using spring-integration.

**Spring-integration.xml**

```html
<bean id="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="10000"/>
    <property name="readTimeout" value="10000"/>
    </bean>


   <bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
    <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
    </property>
    </bean>



<int:gateway id="requestGateway" service-interface="main.java.com.as.poller.RequestGateway"
  default-request-channel="requestchannel" default-reply-timeout="20000">
  <int:method name="pushNotification" />
   </int:gateway>



 <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="pointbalance" 
    uri="url" 
    marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller" 
    request-channel="pointbalancechannel" message-sender="messageSender"
    message-factory="soapMessageFactory">
    <int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
 <int:retry-advice max-attempts="${retry_limit}">
 </int:retry-advice>
 <bean class="main.java.com.as.poller.RetryAdvice" />
    </int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-ws:outbound-gateway>
```

I could find only examples using CommonsHttpMessageSender.But this is deprecated.Can anyone please help me on setting the proxy for HttpComponentsMessageSender for my xml configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I did it using org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender from a superb article https://onebyteatatime.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/spring-web-service-call-using-proxy-per-connection/ . But still i dont see any thing regarding HttpComponentsMessageSender.